# Android: playing a song file using default music player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media

Is there a way to play media with the default media player? I can do this with the following code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
 String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp3");
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(songPath.toString())), type);
 startActivity(intent);
```

But this launches a player with less controls and can't be pushed to the background.
Can I launch the player with the default media player?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the below code:::

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);  
   File file = new File(songPath.toString());  
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
   startActivity(intent);
```

Updated:: Try this also

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();  
   ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.music", "com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity");
   intent.setComponent(comp);
   intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
   File file = new File(songPath.toString());  
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thx! But it does the same thing what my code does. I want to launch the default media player.

Comment: it launches the default player as my thinking.. Also updated my post check it

Comment: The second option worked. We need to set the component object in the intent. Thx!

Comment: I'm getting Activitynotfoundexception when using the second option. I'm not sure why this is happening !!

Comment: I'm getting this log:
 Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.music/com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @SaurabhVerma perhaps default android music player is not installed in your device try running your code in different device or emulator

Answer (score 3):

I've been researching this for the last few days as I don't have the stock music player. It seems so tragic that it can't be done easily. After looking through various music app's AndroidManifest.xml for clues I stumbled upon MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH.

Using the below method I'm able to start the Samsung music player in the background as long as the song is in the Android MediaStore. You can specify Artist, Album or Title. This method also works for Google Play Music but unfortunately even the newest version of the stock Android player does not have this intent:

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml

```
private boolean playSong(String search){
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, search);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // Try other methods here
        return false;
    }
}
```

It would be nice to find a solution that uses a content URI or URL but this solution works for my application.