# Crash while playing a song with default music player

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I want to play some audio files with the default music player. As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867957/android-playing-a-song-file-using-default-music-player/11445075#11445075) post, I've tried the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();  
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.music", "com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity");
    intent.setComponent(comp);
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
    File file = new File(songPath.toString());  
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
    startActivity(intent);
```

But, I'm getting ActivityNotFound Exception with the following logs:

```
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jusplay/com.example.jusplay.playdb}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.music/com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.music/com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
07-12 11:28:49.575: E/AndroidRuntime(22700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
```

I'm unable to figure out why this crash is happening !!

Comment: You register your com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity in Menifest file?

Comment: Yes, inspite of mentioning this: <activity android:name="com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity"></activity> in the manifest file, crash is happening

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jusplay/com.example.jusplay.playdb}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.music/com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`  this line says that your activity is not there in menifest dude.

Comment: have you given the correct path of your activity.i mean do your MediaPlaybackActivity reside under src->com->android->music package??

Comment: It's not my activity. It's inside com.android.music which is exported as "true"

Comment: first remove MediaPlaybackActivity Activity from AndroidManifest then try it becoase this Activity is not part of your Appliction

Comment: Thanks Imran. I've already tried that, but issue still exists.

Comment: @SaurabhVerma : on which android version you are testing it?

Comment: @SaurabhVerma : try this `Intent intent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/mp3");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.music","com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity"));
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: I have tried on 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 (same crash in all the 3 devices)
i've also gone through the manifest file of GingerBread https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/gingerbread/AndroidManifest.xml where I can see that com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity is exported as "true"

Comment: @SaurabhVerma : you can try my code and after removing it from manifast

Comment: I've tried your code Imran and have removed the activity deceleration from the manifest. Still I'm getting the same crash !!

Comment: @SaurabhVerma please post your activity code and your manifest file.